# Vertically Center an image within a Div that has a background image? (Nothing is working)

Tags: html, css, image, center, vertical-alignment

I have been stuck on this all day, please help!
I know that vertical alignment solutions are all over S.O but I can't find (and more importantly understand) an elegant solution to my problem.

I am designing a header/banner to a personal site and while I have managed to center my IMG within it's Container DIV it's way too small. Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">

        <img src="Banner/SODA8.png"/>                         

</div>

.container{
margin-top:50px;
height:200px;
min-height:200px;
background-image:url(hex/hex4.jpg);
background-position: center;
background-repeat:repeat;
background-size:cover;
line-height:300px;
}

.container img{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
vertical-align:middle;
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
display:block;
}
```

Here is the result:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGhOR.jpg

The word 'SODA' is too small, when I alter the max-width and max-height of the IMG('SODA') from 100% to 200% I get the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA26l.jpg

How do I get that size for the IMG whilst still keeping it centered and have this supported by all browsers?

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: could you also post your HTML?

Comment: Yeah sorry,, just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have structure something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="soda.png">
</div>
```

In this case, with the code you've pasted above, if you increase the max-height to 200%, you could apply a negative margin to the image that is half the height of the new size of the image.

I've been using absolute positioning with negative margins to center my images, and just giving up on vertical-align myself. Using a 50% percentage for left and top will allow you to adjust the height or width of the container (if it's sitting in a responsive grid, for example), and then backing the image back out with half it's width and height in a negative margin will center it.

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:50px;
    height:200px;
    min-height:200px;
    background-image:url(hex/hex4.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    line-height:300px;
}

.container img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -(half img width/2)px;
    margin-top: -(half img height/2)px;
    display: block;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pepnr9f7/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I tried putting into my code, the IMG was too large, I then set the min-width/height to 80% and did as you suggested, i.e "apply a negative margin to the image that is half the height of the new size of the image." However this was still too large. I found that I had to quarter the NEW height and width of the IMG. Like so: Orginal size: 1297px, 80% of which is 1038px, quarter of which is 260px. My image is now centered, but I was confused &wondering if you could explain why it had to be quartered ?haha Either way, thanks very much for your answer, it really helped.

Comment: @S_Oda that is really strange. Without seeing your final code, I can't really explain. If you post a link to the final output, I could figure it out.